# data not passing to view laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am just learning laravel and now I am trying to pass data to a view.. but its not passing everytime it gives error:

> View [layouts.{{$admin_theme}}.admin.admin] not found.

**Middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\Readdb;

class Adminlogin {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!$request->session()->has('userid')) {
            $db = new Readdb();
            $admin_theme = $db::get_setting('admin_theme');

            return response()->view('admin.auth.login')->with("admin_theme", $admin_theme);
        } else {
            return response()->view('admin.dash');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

**and this is view:**

```
@extends('layouts.{{$admin_theme}}.admin.admin')
@section('title', 'Mangement Login Area')
```

**Route web.php**

```
Route::get('/auth', function () {
//    This is for admin login. We'll varify if admin is already logged in or not.. if yes, then, we'll redirect.
//    We'll verify it using a middleware adminlogin.
})->middleware('adminlogin');
```

Comment: What file extension your view file has, it should be `viewname.blade.php`.

Comment: yes login.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

`{{` and `}}` are for use inside HTML (or the output sections of the template). When using variables inside Blade constructs, use them like you would with PHP:

```
@extends('layouts.' . $admin_theme . '.admin.admin')
```

Comment: Ok, so now you're actually getting an issue with passing data to the views.  Before, you were evaluating `{{$admin_theme}}` as a string.

Comment: any idea plz what to do ! :(

Comment: You don't have to concat, it is enough to put something like this: `@extends("layouts.$admin_theme.admin.admin")`, note the double quote, the variables inside of that kind of string are evaluated and converted to string automatically.

Comment: Can you post the views directory?, a screenshot or something like that

Comment: not getting what you want me to post.. and still getting same error: Undefined variable: admin_theme (View: /var/www/html/ecommerce/resources/views/admin/auth/login.blade.php)

Comment: @HarenSarma the error no longer seems to be with your view, I'd look to your controller and routes to make sure the right method is being executed.  Try including other variables, then print out what variables are available with get_defined_vars in the view. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Comment: Yeah, but I just want to see your directory structure, sorry if I express myself bad, english is not my main language.

Comment: @HarenSarma, try replacing `response()->view('admin.auth.login')` with just `view('admin.auth.login')`
.  `view()` is a helper function by itself.